# How to rename a existing table name inside database in laravel-8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

I developed one api which is responsible for storing user details inside my database ,The table name is `users_containers`, it will contain some users data now i want to rename that table name to `users_data` without lossing any data ,How to acheive this thing...

`Migration table`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users_containers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
          
        });
    }
```

Comment: you can use all the methods available in the asnwers. Make sure you change the ```protected $table="new_name"``` in model as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new migration:

`php artisan make:migration rename_usercontainers_table`

then add  this code to it:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class RenameUsersContainersTable extends Migration
{
    
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::rename('users_containers', 'users_data');
    }
}
?>
```

then try to run migrate command:
`php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 2):

To change a table name, you can do this:

```
Schema::rename('users_containers', 'users_data');
```

Comment: it's not migrated , it shows nothing to migrate

Comment: @DevopsTraining do not edit the migration you used for creating the table. Create a new migration (you can do this with artisan: `php artisan make:migration rename_users_containers_table`).